A scalar metric on a group of $n$-dimensional points that rewards both closeness to a query point, and consistent "spread" in each dimension?
I have a problem where I need to select a group of $n$-dimensional points out of a grid with missing data (the grid is not perfectly regular, but there is some underlying structure). The selected group of points needs to be approximately the $K >> n$ nearest neighbors to a query point $x$, but also needs to span all $n$ dimensions (the points cannot be co-planar). Obviously, I could do a yes/no check on whether or not the points span the space. But I'd like for the points to "strongly" span the space as well (for instance, I'd like to avoid a sample of points where $K-1$ of them are coplanar, and only one of them causes the group to span the space).
My thought was to cook up some composite metric that rewards minimum mean square distance from the query point as well as "strong spanning" of the space. But I'm not sure how to measure "strength of spanning", and I'm wondering if there is some well-known way of doing this that I'm unaware of (possibly some function of the sample covariance matrix)?
